# Como puedo comparar coordenadas geograficas en android studio y google maps

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, comparaciones

tengo una variable con lo que obtengo mi ubicación y ahora quiero comparar mi ubicacion con un marker fijo ¿Como le puedo hacer? trato de hacer esto

```
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
}


private void prueba() {
    if (mLocationRequest == es igual a la posision fija) {

    }
}
```

Comment: que quieres decir con comparar coordenadas? No puedes obtener las coordenadas del Marker? Indica lo que has pensado o probado para hacerlo

Answer (score -1):

Crea un nuevo objeto `Location` con las coordenadas de tu marcador y luego usa [`distanceTo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) para calcular si la distancia entre el usuario y tu marcador está dentro de un rango dado que será tu margen de error, por ejemplo, 50 metros.

```
private static double THRESHOLD = 50.0;

...

Location markerLocation = new Location("");
markerLocation.setLatitude(marker.getPosition().latitude);
markerLocation.setLongitude(marker.getPosition().longitude);

if (mLocationRequest.distanceTo(markerLocation) < THRESHOLD) {
  ...
}
```